# Get id of innerdiv in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have a iframe that opens different page depending upon the items selected in a menu. Each page in a iframe contains div elements and tables. 
My requirement is to set focus on the first div or table in a iframe. Therefore I am looking for a way to access id of first div or first table and set focus on it.

Since pages loaded in a iframe are depended upon the menu items selected, I couldnot use getElementById method to access elements inside iframe.

I have tried to access first div element in a iframe using following code :

```
 var innerElement = iframeObject.contentWindow.document.getElementsbyTagName('div')[0];
       innerElement.focus();
```

But ,  innerElement is regarded as undefined.

However I was able to set focus on iframe using :

```
 iframeObject.contentWindow.focus();
```

but could not set focus on inner div.

Can anyone help, how could i access the first elements of a iframe?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to reach out a specific HTML element from an external source (URL out of your domain), you can't do that forsake of DOM security reasons!!